# Proving $\sum_{k=1}^n kk!=(n+1)!−1$

Tags: summation, induction, factorial

Ok, so I'm trying to prove statement in the header.  I have read the following discussion on it, but I can't seem to follow it all the way through:

[Proving $\sum_{k=1}^n k k!=(n+1)!-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198735/proving-sum-k-1n-k-k-n1-1/1198743#1198743?newreg=abbcf872d9904cbfa76cd161c4fecdd0)

I like mfl's answer, but I get hung up on the last step.  They say:

and we need to show

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} kk!=(n+2)!−1.$$

Just write

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} kk!=\sum_{k=1}^n kk! + (n+1)(n+1)!$$

How do they get from the first step stated above, to the following step?  I'm stuck.

Comment: If we would have extended the summation to (n+1) terms what would be the (n+1)th term?

Comment: I think it would be $\sum_{k=1}^n kk! + (n+1)! - 1$

Comment: No it isn't.  It would be (n+1)(n+1)!. You must see the general term of the summation and I just asked you the (n+1)$\mathbf {th}$ term not the sum of (n+1) terms. I hope you understood why mfl had written the (n+1)(n+1)! In addition to the summation ( because it is simply the (n+1)th term i.e.last term of the summation in the LHS of last step you mentioned above.). He just wrote that term out of the summation to apply the induction.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n kk!= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} kk!+nn!$$

And by induction we know $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} kk!= n!-1$

Combining we get: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} kk!+nn! =n!-1+nn! = n!(1+n)-1=(n+1)!-1$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to write : $$\sum_{k=1}^n k k!=\sum_{k=1}^n (k+1 -1) k!=\sum_{k=1}^n (k+1)!-k!=(n+1)!-1$$