# Show that $\sum_{m=1}^nm\cdot m!=(n+1)!-1 \forall n\ge 1$

Tags: factorial

I want to show that

$\sum_{m=1}^nm\cdot m!=(n+1)!-1 \forall n\ge 1$, however I am not sure how to do that.

Let $m!=m(m-1)!$ so we replace it in for $m!$ and get

$\sum_{m=1}^nm\cdot m(m-1)! $

which gives

$\sum_{m=1}^nm^2\cdot(m-1)! $

Then let $(m-1)!=(m-1)(m-2)!$ and we obtain

$\sum_{m=1}^nm^2\cdot(m-1)(m-2)! $

but I am still far from the answer. Any ideas on the next steps?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using induction?

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Then I suggest you learn it ASAP. It is one of the most powerful and fundamental tools in a mathematitian's arsenal!

Comment: Assume we know it for $n-1$ in place of $n$, then $$
\sum\limits_{m = 1}^n {m \cdot m!}  = n \cdot n! + \sum\limits_{m = 1}^{n - 1} {m \cdot m!}  =  \ldots 
$$ Can you finish?

Comment: Will try, but I have no reference to a good educational material for induction. Found this https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1142/lectures/03/Small03.pdf

Comment: https://www.studysmarter.co.uk/explanations/math/pure-maths/proof-by-induction/

Comment: @Luthier415Hz Your profile says you are doing a bachelor's in mathematics. If so, the basic calculus textbook you are using, as well as the professor teaching you, are both good sources!

Comment: I do it from home, I have no books for that here. It is in a foreign country, that is  a distance based bachelors.

Comment: @Luthier415Hz So you are doing a bachelors in mathematics and you do not have a single book on basic calculus? How does that work?

Comment: I have books on Calculus, but never seen "induction" in them, I will double check in  Adams.

Comment: @Gary that link is very useful. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving $\sum_{k=1}^n kk!=(n+1)!−1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2610048/proving-sum-k-1n-kk-n1%e2%88%921) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bm%3D1%7D%5Enm%5Ccdot%20m!%3D(n%2B1)!-1%24&p=1). Note there are also quite a few other duplicates here as well, e.g., [Using induction to prove that $\sum_{r=1}^n r\cdot r! =(n+1)! -1$](/q/917367), [Prove by induction that $\sum_{i=1}^n i!\times i=(n+1)!-1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$](/q/813940), ...

Comment: (cont.) [Simplify sum of factorials with mathematical induction](/q/1089542), [Prove $\sum_{j=1}^{n}{j\cdot j!} = (n+ 1)!−1$](/q/4011688), [Understanding an inductive proof that $ \sum_{i=1}^n i\times i! = (n +1)!-1$](/q/2672216), [Proving that $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n k! \cdot k = (n + 1)! - 1$](/q/1164691), etc. There's also AoPS threads, e.g., [Find the sum](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h520988p2934632), [Factorials](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1836741p12319308), [A Proof Involving Factorials](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1196068p5857361), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a typical statement that can be proven by induction.

**Base case**, $n=1$ is trivial, since both sides of the equation equal $1$.

**Induction step**:

Assume that the statement is true for some $n$. Then

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^{n+1} m\cdot m! &= (n+1) (n+1)! + \sum_{m=1}^n m\cdot m! & \text{(by definition of finite sums)}\\
& = (n+1)(n+1)! + (n+1)! - 1&\text{(by the induction hypothesis)}\\
& = (n+1)!\cdot (n+1+1) - 1&\text{(algebraic manipulation)}\\
&= (n+2)\cdot (n+1)! - 1 &\text{(algebraic manipulation)}\\
&= (n+2)! -1&\text{(algebraic manipulation)}
\end{align}$$

which proves the statement for $n+1$, concluding the proof.