# Prove by induction $\sum_{k = 1}^n k \cdot k! = (n + 1)! - 1$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, induction

I was looking at some books that have solutions to this, but I'm wondering which of this is correct, like kk will be the same as k(k)

One is:

Claim: For all $ n \geq 1, \sum_{k=1}^{n} k k !=(n+1) !-1 $.

Proof. Let $S(n) $ denote the statement
$[
S(n): \sum_{k=1}^{n} k k !=(n+1) !-1 .
]$

Base step $ (n=1): S(1) $ is true because $ 1=2 !-1 $.

Inductive step: For some fixed $ \ell \geq 1 $, assume the inductive hypothesis $ S(\ell) $ to be true where
$[
S(\ell): \sum_{k=1}^{\ell} k k !=(\ell+1) !-1 .
]$

To be shown is that $ S(\ell+1) $ follows, where
$[
S(\ell+1): \sum_{k=1}^{\ell+1} k k !=(\ell+2) !-1 .
]$

Starting with the left-hand side of $ S(\ell+1) $,
$[
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^{\ell+1} k k ! & =\sum_{k=1}^{\ell} k k !+(\ell+1)(\ell+1) ! \\
& =[(\ell+1) !-1]+(\ell+1)(\ell+1) ! \\
& =(\ell+1) !(1+\ell+1)-1 \\
& =(\ell+2) \cdot(\ell+1) !-1 \\
& =(\ell+2) !-1,
\end{aligned}
]$
(by definition of $ \Sigma $ )
(by $ S(\ell) $ )
we see that the right-hand side of
$ S(\ell+1) $ follows. This completes the inductive step.

Thus, by mathematical induction, the statement $ S(n) $ is true for all $ n \geq 1 $.

which I don't quite understand but came across this:

If $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k(k !)=(n+1) !-1 $ then
$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k(k !) & =\sum_{k=1}^{n} k(k !)+(n+1)(n+1) ! \\
& =(n+1) !-1+(n+1)(n+1) ! \\
& =(n+2)(n+1) !-1 \\
& =(n+2) !-1
\end{aligned}
$

So with all I think it will be something more like this? Or am I wrong???
Base case: For $ n = 1 $, the left-hand side is $ 1*1! = 1 $ and the right-hand side is $ (1+1)! - 1 = 2! - 1 = 1 $. So the equation holds for $ n = 1 $.

Inductive step: Assume the equation holds for some $ n $, i.e., $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k(k!) = (n+1)! - 1 )$. We need to show that the equation also holds for $( n+1 ), i.e., ( \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k(k!) = (n+2)! - 1 $.

Starting with the left-hand side of the equation for \$ n+1 $:

[
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k(k!) & = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k(k!) + (n+1)((n+1)!) \\
& = (n+1)! - 1 + (n+1)((n+1)!) \quad \text{(by the inductive hypothesis)} \\
& = (n+2)(n+1)! - 1 \\
& = (n+2)! - 1
\end{aligned}
]

Which is the right-hand side of the equation for ( n+1 ). So the equation holds for ( n+1 ) if it holds for ( n ), completing the induction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combinatorial proof of $\sum_{k=1}^n k k!=(n+1)!-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198735/combinatorial-proof-of-sum-k-1n-k-k-n1-1)

Comment: The header of the duplicate refers to a combinatorial proof, but several of the posted solutions offer complete proofs by induction.

Comment: oh sorry i copied from the latex file

Comment: @peterwhy i already changed it ty

Comment: @lulu now that i looked at it you are right but i wanted to check if my aproach is correct or if i messed it ;o but tysm

Comment: What did you "don't quite understand" for the first proof? It seems that the difference between the two induction steps is the use of $\ell$ or $n$.

Comment: @peterwhy the S, what it stands for, um my main language isn't english so the western letters confuse me a little

Comment: For each $n$, $S(n)$ is the true-or-false statement "$\sum_{k=1}^n kk! = (n+1)!-1$". As in you may substitute the claim "$S(1)$ is true" by "$\sum_{k=1}^1 kk! = (1+1)!-1$".

Comment: ohhh so if I want to change it i only will have to substitute the l for n?